# Deploying a static site on AWS EC2/nginx: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, static-content

I set up a micro instance (Ubuntu, 32 bit) and assigned an elastic IP (23.23.245.104)

Public DNS: ec2-23-23-245-104.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I successfully ssh'ed to the machine and installed nginx.

Then I edited the server_name attribute in nginx's config file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default)

```
server_name ec2-23-23-245-104.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
```

Restarted nginx and hit http://ec2-23-23-245-104.compute-1.amazonaws.com but got a "could not connect" error.

What did I forget to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably forgot to add TCP port 80 to your security group in the AWS console.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! It works. Thanks for the blazing fast response. I can accept your answer in 10 minutes. Thanks again